# How to change all phone numbers on a page to clickable links, excluding a specifically classed element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to transform all phone numbers entered through a CMS into clickable phone numbers. Basically, I want this 800-777-0000 to be transformed into this:

```
<a href="tel:8007770000">800-777-0000</a>
```

However, I do not want buttons (which are already formatted properly) to be altered. So, this item should remain untouched:

```
<a href="tel:8007770000" class="button">Call Today</a>
```

I'm about 99.999% of the way there with my pen on Codepen http://codepen.io/vaughndtaylor/pen/XdGqjL, but I'm not sure how to exclude elements with a "button" class?

===

EDIT:

I modified the code below like this:

```
$.each($('.content-cms').find('p, ol, ul, h2, h3, h4, h5, div:not(.button-row), a:not(.button)'), function(i, value) {
  console.log(value);
  $(value).html(ReplacePhoneNumbers($(value).html()));
});
```

Comment: can't get your point..

Comment: Looking at the Codepen, you'll see that all of the HTML in the "content-cms" div is passed into a function that does regex matching to find a pattern matching a phone number. When it finds a phone number, it transforms the phone number string (eg. 1-888-555-9999) into a clickable phone number. But, I want the function to ignore any element with a "button" class. I'm having problems sorting that out. Make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-- EDITED after properly understandment --

If you don't have nested .button elements, this should work:

Replace:

```
$(".content-cms").html(ReplacePhoneNumbers($(".content-cms").html()));
```

with:

```
$.each($(".content-cms").find('*').not('.button'), function(index,value) 
{
    $(value).html(ReplacePhoneNumbers($(value).html()));
});
```

Comment: You understood the question properly. I tried that solution before I posted, but when implemented the phone number does not change? I've modified the pen with your line, and the old line in comments.

Comment: I see now.. You're using a regex to replace entire content. Edited, take a look.

Comment: Just be aware that you can't have, let's say, `<p><a button with number></a>some text</p>`, this will not work. In your example, this solution will work, but if you have nested elements with `class="button"` it won't work and we'll have to find a different solution.

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you're saying. It's very possible that I may have buttons wrapped in a div for example. So, what would the solution be in that case? I've updated my pen to include that scenario.